# How to validate password in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get at least 1 lowercase, at least 1 uppercase, at least 1 number, 1 other and password must be under 8 characters.

Here is my validation code :

```
const strongRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})");

strongRegex.test("Abd1$bas") // true it works fine 
strongRegex.test("Abd1$bass") // Here is 9 characters , currently: true .
```

now, if characters are more than 8, it gives me true, but I don't get true
My question is that if characters more than 8 then it gives me false.

Answer (score 0):

The last assertion is a positive lookahead `(?=.{8,})` and checks if there are more than 8 characters at the right.

In your case you want to validate that there a not 9 characters at the right, for which you can use a negative lookahead `(?!.{9})`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dnWSVs/1)

```js
const strongRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?!.{9})");

console.log(strongRegex.test("Abd1$bas"))
console.log(strongRegex.test("Abd1$bass"))
```